# How can I get specific users posted data from Mongo dB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

In react application I used a form to inserted data and with express JS I post this data to mongo db.
when people is logged in the can insert data using form. and there is a page where user can view and delete their inserted data. **Problem is how can I load data that was inserted by specific user?**

Comment: use findOne condition of mongo DB with your userid condition like findOne({userId : 'yourUserId'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When any user log in and user insert data also store **user_id** with
> every entry. Now get data from **DB** by using current user logged in
> **user_id** and display that specific data on front end. That's it.

Comment below for any query.
Thanks